# Problems running GLM with count data

Tags: r, modeling, glm, multilevel-analysis

I'm using eBird count data to try and look at changes in bird distributions over time throughout the urban gradient. I'm an undergrad so my stats level is pretty limited. I took the relative count (observed count/total count in a year) of observations from 2003 to 2023. I'm trying to run a GLM poisson right now but it is not going very well. Any advice on this model or another model would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I didn't transform my data, it is not normal

I tried running this code:

```
glm_interactions<-glmer(RelCount~ urban_category*year+ latitude + longitude + number_observers + day_of_year + (1|county) + (1|protocol_type), family="poisson", data = DF)
```

But it gave me

```
50+ warnings (1: In (function (fr, X, reTrms, family, nAGQ = 1L, verbose = 0L,  ... :
  non-integer x = 0.000321)
```

Comment: To get better, faster help you should edit this question to provide a minimal reproducible example, see here for some tips on how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example